# Increasing size of .glusterfs directory

Tags: storage, glusterfs

I'm using glusterfs 3.3 version.
One of my mounted drive (15TB) is show full. After checking, I got that there is a directory .glusterfs which is uses 3TB.
I don't know the actual reason of .glusterfs directory is there any impact if I delete the .glusterfs directory? Or is there any way to limit the increase size of the directory?
Thanks